# bash does not recognize alt+backspace command

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I use bash and alt+backspace key to delete a word at a time. This works nicely, but for some reason, it stops working after a while. It seems as though it does not recognize the alt key, and simply removes a character at a time.

Btw, I use screen to fork multiple bash instances.

I'd appreciate any solutions or diagnostic suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: Does it stop working after you use a specific command? Start a new window?

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
bind -q backward-kill-word
```

it should respond with:

```
backward-kill-word can be invoked via "\e\C-h", "\e\C-?".
```

If not, you can do one or both of:

```
bind '"\e\C-h": backward-kill-word'
bind '"\e\C-?": backward-kill-word'
```

You only need one. You can tell which by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> which will output either `^H` or `^?`.

You should't need to, but you can add the following to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e\C-h": backward-kill-word
"\e\C-?": backward-kill-word
```